# Migrate TFS 2018 (OS Win 2016, SQL Server 2017) to Azure Devops server (OS Win 2019, SQL Server 2019)

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am trying to find path to migrate TFS 2018 (OS Win 2016, SQL Server 2017) to a new machine with OS Win 2019 and SQL Server 2019.

On new machine I am planning to install Azure Devops 2020, but I am not sure about migrations steps.

Will I first do migration of TFS databases from TFS 2018 (migration db and objects)?

After that I will install Azure Devops 2020 with point to migrated/restored DB from TFS2018.

I am confused, about documentation, because I found that I need to do whole process of upgrade on old TFS2018 machine (OS->2019, DB->2019, TFS ->Azure Devops), and after that migrate to new machine.

But I hope that I can do migrate/restore DB on new SQL Server 2019, and after that during Azure Devops 2020, choose restored DB and etc...

Please any info would be appreciated

Thank you for your time,
Keli

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the TFS Admin Console backup your existing TFS databases.
2. Copy the backup files to the new SQL server and restore them
3. Install Azure DevOps Server on the new target server but don't configure it
4. On the new Azure DevOps Server use Scheduled Backups - Restore Databases

I believe this will work if the source server was 2017 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob, for response.

I succeeded, but my path was a little different because I had TFS server with SQL Enterprise Edition, and I needed to do migration of databases to 2019 Standard Edition:

1. Install new virtual machine (VMNew) with: Windows 2019, SQL Server 2019 (Standard Edition).
   On this machine I install Azure Devops 2020, but I didn't configure it.
2. On my TFS server (Windows 2016, SQL 2017 Enterprise Edition) I did
   backup all databases with TFS administration console
3. On new VMNew server, with Azure Devops Console, I did restore databases, but only
   ConfigurationDB and CollectionDB.
   Restore of ReportingServicesDB and WarehouseDB wasn't possible, because
   my old TFS server was SQL Enterprise Edition.
4. After successfully restored ConfigurationDB and CollectionDB on VMNew, I
   configured Azure Devops feature through Console. And site is started successfully.
5. ReportingServices and Warehouse I configured after step 4. also, through
   Azure Devops Console.

Hope that this info will help someone.

Kind regards,
Keli